# Checking if a value is IN a colon separated column with in a table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, parsing

I have a small problem I could tackle quite easily in C# but I have been asked to do it within the SQL.

I have a Stored procedure which takes in an int as a parameter, and I need to check if that parameter is inside the value of a colon seperated column in the database.

```
(
                                (
                                    gvf_permitted_projects is null
                                ) 
                                or 
                                (   -- @activeProject IN gvf_permitted_projects
                                    -- @activeProject = 11
                                    -- gvf_permitted_projects = '11:17'
                                )
                            )
```

This is inside the where clause of my SELECT, I could do this in C# with minimal effort but I'm not too sure how to do it here. Do I need to use a temp table and then do a select into that?

Comment: How is the colon separated column in the database, any specific order followed. A sample input data with case would help.

Comment: You could use a custom split T-SQL function. Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string

Comment: it's just as shown in the comments, 11:17

The numbers chosen there are just examples. But I would want it to return true as 11 is in the lsit

Comment: If I used a split string function? Could I implement that within my where clause?

Comment: I am guessing this query might just work, just check the same in your `WHERE` clause- 
`PATINDEX('%'+CAST(@activeProject AS VARCHAR(10))+'%',@gvf_permitted_projects)`

Comment: You should fix your database structure so you are not storing integers as strings, and you only have one value in a column.  In this case, you want to use a junction table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like operator with some text manipulation, although this will be somewhat slow and normalised structure would be preferred anyway:

```
':'+@gvf_permitted_projects+':' like '%:'+cast(@activeProject as varchar(20))+':%'
```

Answer (score 0):

So you would have to split your string into columns. If you're not allowed to use functions, you can use this: [Splitting Delimited Strings Using XML in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/)

Quick demo how does this work:

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML
    , @str AS VARCHAR(100)
    , @delimiter AS VARCHAR(1)

SET @str = '11:17'
SET @delimiter = ':'
SET @xml = cast(('<X>' + replace(@str, @delimiter, '</X><X>') + '</X>') AS XML)

SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS value
FROM @xml.nodes('X') AS T(N)
```

It brings back this:

```
╔═══════╗
║ value ║
╠═══════╣
║    11 ║
║    17 ║
╚═══════╝
```

So this would be your SQL:

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE
(
    Id INT
    , gvf_permitted_projects VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @YourTable (Id, gvf_permitted_projects)
VALUES (1, '11:17')
    , (2, '11:13')
    , (3, '12:17');

SELECT *
FROM @YourTable AS YT
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST(('<X>' + replace(gvf_permitted_projects , ':', '</X><X>') + '</X>') AS XML)
    ) AS V(N)
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM N.nodes('X') AS T(N)
        WHERE N.value('.', 'INT') = 11
        );
```

That's result:

```
╔════╦════════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ Id ║ gvf_permitted_projects ║         N          ║
╠════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ 11:17                  ║ <X>11</X><X>17</X> ║
║  2 ║ 11:13                  ║ <X>11</X><X>13</X> ║
╚════╩════════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

Although, I'd strongly recommend to normalize your data structure. This is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I added up some nice tricks you can do with XML and string values:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33658220/5089204

Go to the "Dynamic IN" section. Hope this helps.