# Sql Server 2012 How to Get List on Function

Tags: sql-server-2012

Function Details:

```
alter FUNCTION siralama_puan (@suggestion_id int)
RETURNS int
AS
Begin
     Declare @comment_count int,@like_count int,@favorite_count int,@date_point int,@suggestion_point int,@suggestion_date datetime,@fark int

     set @comment_count=(select [Suggestion].CommentCount from [Suggestion] where  [Suggestion].Id= @suggestion_id)
     set @like_count=(select [Suggestion].LikeCount from [Suggestion] where [Suggestion].Id=@suggestion_id)
     set @favorite_count=(select [Suggestion].FavoriteCount from [Suggestion] where [Suggestion].Id=@suggestion_id)
     set @suggestion_date=(select [Suggestion].Crtm from [Suggestion] where [Suggestion].Id=@suggestion_id)
     set @fark =(select DATEDIFF(day,@suggestion_date,GETDATE()))

     if @fark<6  
     set @date_point=30
    else if @fark<10 and @fark>=6
     set @date_point=20
    else
    set @date_point=10

     set @suggestion_point=(@comment_count*2)+(@like_count)+(@favorite_count*3)+@date_point
     RETURN @suggestion_point
End
```

Calling Function:

```
select dbo.siralama_puan  (122280,1) as puan order by puan desc
```

but it didn't work.Error:Procedure or function dbo.siralama_puan has too many arguments specified.Multiple arguments not working.

Comment: well, of course it doesn't work because your function receives only one argument. What's your question?

Comment: i want to send multiple id.

Comment: and what would be the result of that?

Comment: You need to alter the function parameter to take comma separated id's. And then convert the comma separated ids into temp table and loop through the temp table rows and r insert into a table variable and return the table.

Comment: @ashy, the comma separated list is just one - and at least for me not the best - approach... Better use `CREATE TYPE` or XML (see my answer).

Comment: You could set all variables at once. There is no need for multiple `SET`.
*`SELECT @comment_count = CommentCount, @like_count = LikeCount ... FROM  [Suggestion] WHERE Id=@suggestion_id`*. Anyway passing multiple ids you probably has to change entire SP body to be set-based no  one-row-based.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to define one parameter of type INT and pass in a list. But there are several approaches:

#### TYPE

Create your own type with `CREATE TYPE` [read here...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). This allows you to pass in a list very similar to a (read only) table

#### XML

Let your parameter be of type XML and pass in something like

```
<root>
   <prm value="122280"/>
   <prm value="1"/>
</root>
```

It's quite easy to transform this XML within your function to a list with something like

```
SELECT Prm.value('@value','int') AS PrmValue
FROM @prm.nodes('/root/prm') AS One(Prm)
```

#### CSV

A parameter of type `VARCHAR(MAX)` and a comma separated list like "122280,1". Find a way to split this [here: section "Dynamic IN-statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33658220/5089204)