# lambda query data like sql where not in

Tags: sql-server

in my database i save users tag in table
the table structure is
Table Name : User

```
Id Name   Tags
1  Jack   White,Yellow,Green
2  smith  Yellow,Green
3  smith  Blank
```

....

the condition is:

```
string[] tags = {"Yellow","Green"};
```

I hope can get the data from database,so this is my lambda:

```
 unitOfWork.Repository<User>().find(x=>!x.Any(x.Tag.......);
```

the sql like:

```
Select * from Users Where Tags not in('Yellow','Green')
```

but the tags in database is long string with ","

Comment: The best option is to normalize your schema so that `Tags` becomes a table that is linked to `Users` with a `optional one to many` relationship. Is that possible?

Comment: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33658220/5089204) I placed an example how one could create an `IN` clause form a delimited string dynamically. But Igor is right: Your data is breaking 1NF. This is something you should never do...

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? Starting with 2016 you might use the new built-in Split method...

Comment: The best solution is to fix the schema and create a separate table to match IDs to tags. You could use a free text search query to search for specific words, but that's a bit of overkill. You could also *cache* non-sensitive user data (eg ID and tags only? maybe name?) and generate a dictionary keyed by Tag to allow quick searches on the cached items

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have big data, this is not a good solution But you can after you select all data.

```
var result = db.Users.ToList()
               .Where(i => i.Tags.Split(',').Any(t => tags.Contains(t))).ToList();
```

I think, `normalize your schema` looks like better.

**Other option**:

You can use `SqlQuery`

```
class Users
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
}


string[] tags = {"Yellow","Green"};

var whereClause = String.Join(" OR ", tags.Select(i => String.Format("Tags LIKE %{0}%", i));

var query = String.Format(@"
                            SELECT 
                                * 
                            FROM 
                                Users 
                            Where 
                                {0}
                           ", whereClause);

var result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Users>(query);
```

Query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Users 
Where 
    Tags LIKE %Yellow% OR Tags LIKE %Green%
```

Comment: This is a bad solution even if you have very little data. You are loading *everything* in memory just to do a split on a field. At least, load *only* the tag and ID, not the entire user object. Once you find the matching IDs, you can do another query to load the relevant objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I dont think so. `This is a bad solution even if you have very little data`

Comment: You are loading everything in memory (including any blobs like pictures etc), then scan every row without any benefit of indexing generating temporary string objects, just to find a subset of users. This will be a constant waste of RAM, CPU (due to scanning, splitting *and* garbage collection) and bandwidth, repeated for each individual request. This can work only by loading only what's necessary, caching the data to avoid needless querying, and generate a dictionary upon loading to avoid searching all users.

Comment: That is why I said that `If you have big data, this is not good solution` If you have little data (`including any blobs like pictures etc`) 
The impact will not be much.

Comment: For a web application it's not the size of the data that matters so much as the frequency of requests. A bad approach will kill a site if it has even moderate traffic. In combination this approach would fail even for small sites (which typically run on *small* servers). It's *not* hard to implement a good solution for this problem

Comment: Sometimes all developers are forced to resort to this method. Performance or Load testing will reveal if there are problems in practice.