# How can i pass 'A0101', 'A0201' like an array fo strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pass 'A0101',  'A0201' this like a parameter in sql server query using in clause but from c# to a sp

Comment: Search out using this query "pass data table to procedure c#"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: [You might read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33658220/5089204), Section "Dynamic IN statement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "IN" clause is just being used to filter, you can use Linq without passing it into the stored procedure (it will still be evaluated on server with deferred execution).

```
 var results = (from item in context.SPCall
     where new[] {"A0101", "A0201"}.Contains(item.Property)
     select item).ToList();
```